# Java Script to Trigger Dependent HTML Select Drop Down Changes on Web Page

Tags: html, jquery, html-select

I have the script below to update one drop down list 'modelddl' based on the value of 'makeddl'.
While both drop downs are displaying their relevant list of items independently from an SQLite DB the script does prompt a dependent change, so basically the script is not working but I can't tell why. appreciate any help on this as I have been stuck on this for some time now.

```
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function()
        {
                var $makevar = $("#makeddl");
                    $modelvar = $("#modelddl");
                    $options = $modelvar.find('option');
                    $makevar.on('change',function()
                    {
                    $modelvar.html($options.filter('[value="' + this.value + '"]'));
                    }).trigger('change');
        });
    </script>
</head>



<h2>Pick a Car</h2> 
            <! -- Drop Downs -->
            <form method="POST" action = "DUMMY ACTION - ACTION_OR_VIEW_URL_ON_SUBMIT_HERE" enctype='multipart/form-data'>{% csrf_token %}
                <label for="makeddl">Choose Make</label>
                {<select id="makeddl">
                    <option  disabled selected="true">Choose Make</option>
                    {% for makes in MotorMakesView %}
                    <option value="{{ makes.id}}"> {{ makes.MotorMakeName }} </option>      
                    {% endfor %}
                </select>
            <br><br>
            
            <label for="modelddl">Choose Model</label>
                <select id="modelddl"> 
                    <option disabled selected ="true">Model</option>
                    {% for mods in MotorModelsView %}
                    <option value="{{ mods.MotorMakeName}}"> {{ mods.MotorModelName}} </option> 
                    {% endfor %}
                </select>}
            <br><br>
           
        <! -- Submit Button -->

            <input type="submit" value="Get Offers"/>
        </form>
```

**View.py**

```
def home(request):
"""Renders the home page."""

displayMake=MotorMakes.objects.all()
displayModel=MotorModelsV2.objects.all()
 })
```

Example of some Data

**MotorMakesView**

id, MotorMakeName
1, Alfa Romeo /n
2, Audi /n
3, BMW /n

**MotorModelsView** Mkid is the fk between both tables;

id,Mkid,MotorMakeName, MotorModel
1,1,Alfa Romeo, Guiletti /n
2,1,Alfa Romeo, Stelvio /n
3,2,Audi,A1 /n
4,2,Audi,A2 /n
5,2,Audi,A3 /n
6,3,BMW, 1 Series /n

Comment: Where is the change event dispatched?

Comment: You are missing **c** letter in **function** in your code
```$(document).ready(funtion()``` . Please check @johnperc

Comment: You have use `val` in option  it should be `value`

Comment: thanks @RayeesAC - updated that above

Comment: Thanks @Swati updated the code for "value", it has not resolved the issue though.

Comment: Do you want to trigger change on  $makevar or  $modelvar? because your code is wtching the change and triggering the change on $makevar variable, is it correct?

Comment: @h3nr1ke -the makevar variable when selected is passed as a parameter in a filter for the modelvar, so the value of makeddl impacts the available values in modelddl.

Comment: @johnperc, sure sure... so you need to trigger change in the $modelvar... because you chaged the options in the $makevar, something like this ```$modelvar.html($options.filter('[value="' + this.value + '"]'));
    $modelvar.trigger('change');```

and also, you need to take care, since you are doing a HTML replacemente, you will lose the ```<option disabled selected ="true">Model</option>```

Comment: @h3nr1ke I am working with this code which appears identical to your suggestion except the syntax on the .trigger, is there something to change there? 
#                                                                             
$makevar.on('change',function()
                  {
                        $modelvar.html($options.filter('[value="' + this.value + '"]'));
                        }).trigger('change'); #

Comment: Got it, the makevar and the modelvar  option values had to originate with the same data point - that surprised me as I thought the filter value would be the key value. comments above certainly helped with cleaning up errors, so many thanks to all.

Answer (score 0):

Both of the option values for both drop downs appear to need to have originated from the same field.
I was surprised at that as I thought the key thing would be the value for the filter on the second drop down only.

```
<br><br>
                <label for="makeddl">Choose Make</label>
                    {<select id="makeddl">
                        <option  disabled selected="true">Choose Make</option>
                        {% for makes in MotorMakesView %}
                        <option value ="{{ makes.MotorMakeName}}"> {{ makes.MotorMakeName }} </option>      
                        {% endfor %}
                    </select>
                <br><br>
            
            <label for="modelddl">Choose Model</label>
                <select id="modelddl"> 
                    <option disabled selected ="True">Model</option>
                    {% for mods in MotorModelsView %}
                    <option value="{{ mods.MotorMakeName}}"> {{ mods.MotorModelName}} </option> 
                    {% endfor %}
                </select>}
            <br><br>
```